# PL/SQL Object Inheritance - using base constructor that has a parameter

Tags: inheritance, plsql

I have the following code that demonstrates the problem:

```
create type base_class as object (
  v number
  ,constructor function base_class(i_v number) return self as result
  ,member procedure print
) not instantiable not final;

create type body base_class as
  constructor function base_class(i_v number)
  return self as result
  is
  begin
     v := i_v;
  end;

  member procedure print
  is
  begin
     dbms_output.put_line('V is ' || v);
  end;
end;

create type derived under base_class (
  constructor function derived return self as result
);

create type body derived as
  constructor function derived
  return self as result
  is
  begin
     base_class(5); -- This bit is the problem
  end;
end;
/
```

In the derived constructor I wish to use the `base_class` constructor passing in a value. I have been unable to find out how to do this.

The attempt above I get the error *Error(6,6): PLS-00221: 'BASE_CLASS' is not a procedure or is undefined*

Does anybody know how I can achieve the objective of using the base classes constructor with a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible. This is a limitation of PL/SQL.

The best alternative is to declare an initializer member procedure inside base class and then call it in both base and derived class constructors.

Comment: Is it possible to make the base `not instantiable not final` then hide the initialisation function in the derived?

Comment: Not sure, I think no. But following your idea you don't need to have an initializator member procedure declared in a not instantiable base class. You can just declare in the derived class a constructor doing all the initializations.

Comment: I was trying to have the initialisation code in one place - not in the two or three derived classes i.e. derived_one, derived_two.

Comment: I know, of course. I didn't found any better solution in PL/SQL than declaring an initializer member procedure. This is not really OOP, but PL/SQL is not an OO language